# Get Text from "href" with dojo?

Tags: javascript, dojo

i 've the following html:

```
<table id="mytable">
    <thead>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="#" onclick="doSometThingCrazy(); return false;">test</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Now i want to get all links inside this table with dojo. So far so good:

```
  dojo.query("#mytable a").forEach(
          function(item){
               dojo.connect(item, 'onmouseover', function(){
                   console.log(item);
                   console.log('x');
               });
          }
     );
```

Now i want to get the text for the href (test) and look for it in an other table. Is there anyway to access this value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check its innerHTML, I do not know any css selector for its innerHTML.

```
 dojo.query("#mytable a").forEach(
      function(item){
           if(dojo.attr(item, "innerHTML") == "TEXT")
               dojo.connect(item, 'onmouseover', function(){
                   console.log(item);
                   console.log('x');
               });
      }
 );
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want text and no HTML markup to worry about, use:

```
dojo.dom.textContent(item)
```